# Installing rgdal on MacOS with Anaconda RStudio

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, rgdal, proj

I have downloaded, compiled, and installed the necessary prerequisites (PROJ and GDAL). I ran the following command in RStudio:

```
install.packages("rgdal",lib="/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/library", configure.args = "--with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Versions/4B/unix/include --with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Versions/4B/unix/lib")
```

All of the checks and configurations work until...

```
checking proj_api.h presence and usability... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
```

This happens in spite of the fact that I specified the correct path for the include folder in the `install.packages()` call. I have also tried pointing to the Headers folder where the `proj_api.h` file is located, but that doesn't work either. Any insights into where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I had a similar problem with the `proj_api.h` and was able to solve it with this [GitHub](https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom/issues/28#issuecomment-478325216) comment. Hope it helps!